# How to decide the compactness of the set $S=\left\{\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n},(-1)^n \right) : \, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

I need to decide whether $$S=\left\{\left(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n},(-1)^n \right) : \, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $$ is a compact set or not.

---

I think it is not a compact set since it is not a closed set because $(0,1)\in S'$ but $(0,1)\notin S$ so that $S'\not\subset S$ , then it cannot be a closed set.

However I'm not sure about this reasoning because I can't prove $S$ is an open set.

Comment: You are correct! But the set is not open either; do not forget that sets can be neither closed nor open.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is correct. That is, your argument proves that $S$ is not closed. Since all compact sets are closed, $S$ is not compact.

The set $S$ is not open. Why would you want to prove that?